# Gradle downloading too slow how to download it manual?

Tags: android-studio

"I am currently using Linux Mint LMDE6.

```
Android Studio: Hedgehog | 2023.1.1
```

> Kotlin version: 231-1.9.10-release-459-AS9392.1.2311.11076708

I am working on a Kotlin project and encountering an issue while downloading the Gradle binary zip in Android Studio. The download speed is extremely slow, and it often stops suddenly, restarting from the beginning.

For example, should I download it manually, and if so, where should I put it?

What steps can I take to address this issue?"